# Unable to connect to google.com

Tags: windows-10, internet

A very strange thing recently happened to my laptop.  When I'm on my work network, I cannot browse to google.com.  Other websites are fine, and I can ping google.com.  I have tried all browsers: Chrome, Firefox and Edge.  After about a minute of spinning, Chrome comes back with:

> Internal Error: Missing Template ERR_CONNECT_FAIL

Other computers on the same network do not have this problem.  So obviously it's a problem with my laptop, right?

So I took my laptop home, and on my home network, everything works 100%.

So what we have here is a corner case where (a) only on my computer, (b) only on my work network, and (c) only when surfing to google.com, the communication fails.

Any ideas?  (And yes, I have tried rebooting...:p)

Comment: I'd suggest engaging with your works IT people and seeing if they have anything to suggest on this. They may have a proxy, or other such setup that is causing your machine to be different...

Comment: What happens I'd you try to telnet to Google with `telnet www.google.com 80`? You may need to install the telnet client feature first.

Comment: Have the error also appear in browser incognito mode? If it doesn't, hence the content filtering, firewall or proxy setting may cause the problem. If it working properly, then an extension or local security settings may mess things up.

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto The problem is the same in incognito mode

Comment: @Twisty I'm not an expert in how to use telnet, but the initial connection works.

Comment: The fact you can connect with telnet indicates some sort of filtering/intercepting is taking place. Try booting to [safe mode with networking](http://www.digitalcitizen.life/4-ways-boot-safe-mode-windows-10) and see if you can browse to Google then. Also, look at your browsers config...is a proxy configured?

Comment: @Twisty - the problem is across all browsers, even the ones I don't usually use.  Internet settings show no proxy server set up.

Comment: Then try in Safe Mode. If nothing changes, then I'm thinking something outside your machine on your work network is blocking your traffic.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yep, there was a firewall issue.  The office network was going through an online firewall server.  No idea why it was picking on my particular computer, but the network admin put me in a group that exempted me from content filtering, and now I'm working again.